# HTML Template Rendering - Odd behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css

See the Pen [Inventory-Bananza](https://codepen.io/johnsoct/pen/PReEmN/) by Chris Johnson ([@johnsoct](https://codepen.io/johnsoct)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

The issue I'm experiencing is at this line of code:

```
// Item's inventory state: in stock || order
console.log(container);
if (item.numLeft <= 100) container.classList.add('bg-order');
```

I'm trying to render certain template containers red if they are below a certain `.numLeft,` but once it finds the first `item.numLeft` below the threshold (100), all the following containers are red. I'm not sure if I'm not understanding how templates work or I'm doing something incorrectly while iterating over the items.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `if (item.numLeft == 100)` ? It will work only when `numLeft` is exactly 100

Comment: @Justinas I need every item (rendered using the template) to have a red background if the item's number left is lower than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that is being rendered is a clone of the last one.  So, you have to remove the class in the case that it is > 100, and this can be done just by adding an else statement:

```
// Item's inventory state: in stock || order
console.log(container);
if (item.numLeft <= 100) {
    container.classList.add('bg-order'); 
} else { 
    container.classList.remove('bg-order');
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this worked and I've used this logic plenty of times, but I don't understand why it applies to all containers if they don't meet the condition set (`<= 100`). Any insight?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - It looks like it is an issue of `block vs function scope` related to the `const container = ...;` statement.  According to [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) 'const' means that the identifier cannot be reassigned.  I am not 100% clear on this type of problem, but it has certainly come up for me in the past.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the lookup. I'll make sure to keep it in my back pocket.